# Logically merge arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some data of a single entity being distributed across multiple tables in a mysql database. When I fetch this data, I end up with separate arrays containing data of the same logical entity. So I want to logically merge these separate arrays for ease to work with it on my app. A simpler example would be:

arrays:

```
cakes = [
          {id: 1, name: 'A'},
          {id: 2, name: 'B'},
          {id: 3, name: 'C'}
         ]

flavours = [
             {id: 1, cakeId: 2, flavour: 'mint'},
             {id: 2, cakeId: 2, flavour: 'strawberry'},
             {id: 3, cakeId: 3, flavour: 'mint'}
           ]
```

The goal is to merge these two arrays into a single array, respecting the reference to the cake array (cakeId) in the flavours array. The final array I would expect in this example would be:

```
newCakesArray = [
                 {id: 1, name: 'A'},
                 {id: 2, name: 'B', flavours: {id: 1, cakeId: 2, flavour: 'mint'},
                                              {id: 2, cakeId: 2, flavour: 'strawberry'}},
                 {id: 3, name: 'C', flavours: {id: 3, cakeId: 3, flavour: 'mint'}}
                ]
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `reduce` to iterate over the `cakes` array. Inside call back function use filter to get the objects from `flavors` by matching `id` & `cakeId`. If the accumulator object have and key by same as cake `id` then update or create the `flavour` key. After iteration use `Object.values` to get the final array

```js
let cakes = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'A'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'B'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'C'
  }
]

let flavours = [{
    id: 1,
    cakeId: 2,
    flavour: 'mint'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    cakeId: 2,
    flavour: 'strawberry'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    cakeId: 3,
    flavour: 'mint'
  }
]

let newData = cakes.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let getFlavours = flavours.filter(item => item.cakeId === curr.id);

  if (!acc[curr.id]) {
    acc[curr.id] = curr;
  }
  if (getFlavours.length > 0) {
    acc[curr.id].flavours = getFlavours

  }

  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(newData))
```

Comment: This works. Would this also work for very large arrays length around 300k plus?

Comment: Here you have higher complexity because for every `cake` there's an additional cycle with `.filter` that means for N cakes there are 1+N cycles (reduce + all filters). In my answer there're 2 cycles regardless amount of cakes.

Comment: I answer his question because with 300k amount of cycles matters.

Comment: @satanTime browsers probably will never guarantee performance when iterating 300k elements unless service worker is used.

Comment: That's why people should write optimized code. if you know your visitor can be on a slow laptop - simply skip 300k of cycles and run just 2 to give him / her a better user experience.

Comment: You are welcome and I'm very sorry that my answer touched you in a rude manner. I think the goal of the platform is to help people with concerns they have and if an author wonders whether an answer works with 300k we should give him info about that too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cakes = [
          {id: 1, name: 'A'},
          {id: 2, name: 'B'},
          {id: 3, name: 'C'}
         ];

var flavours = [
             {id: 1, cakeId: 2, flavour: 'mint'},
             {id: 2, cakeId: 2, flavour: 'strawberry'},
             {id: 3, cakeId: 3, flavour: 'mint'}
           ];

// let's create an index table based on the id field.
var cakesObs = {};
for (var cake of cakes) {
  cakesObs[cake.id] = Object.assing({}, cake); // cloning cake to avoid  changes in the original object
  cakesObs[cake.id].flavours = []; // an empty array by default.
}

// adding flavours to the index table
for (var flavour of flavours) {
  cakesObs[flavour.cakeId].flavours.push(flavour);
}

// converting the table back to an array of cakes but now with flavours.
var newCakesArray = Object.values(cakesObs);
```

Comment: Would this work for very large arrays length around 300k plus?

Comment: Yes, it will. It uses pointers for `flavours`, the question is only for `cakes`, if you don't need the original object and it's fine to mutate it simply replace `cakesObs[cake.id] = Object.assing({}, cake)` with `cakesObs[cake.id] = cake`.

Comment: thanks. i appreciate your reply. i upvoted your answer but it wont show as my reputation in the platform is not enough to consider upvotes publicly.

Comment: Thanks, the main thing if the solution does what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over cakes array and add "flavours" property. For checking which objects in flavours array should be added, use "filter" function.

```
for (const i in cakes) {
  const cakeId = cakes[i].id;
  cakes[i].flavours = flavours.filter(f => f.cakeId === cakeId)
}
```

Comment: for some reason the inserted object is logging out as "cakes: [[Object], [Object], [Object]]" on console.

Comment: I see this approach does work as well. Would it work for very large arrays length 300k+ too?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about ordering in both arrays you can do something like this:

```
cakes.map(cake => {
   const flavours = flavours.find(f => f.cakeId === cake.id);
   if(flavours) return {
     ...cake,
     flavours
   }
  return cake;
})
```

If you worry about space complexity and don't want to create another array you can do it in place

```
for(let i=0;i<cakes.length;i++) {
    const flavours = flavours.find(f => f.cakeId === cake.id);
    if(flavours) cakes[i].flavours = flavours;
}
```

In order to reduce the time complexity associated with searching for correct cakeId within flavors objects (the search is made in every iteration that is very expensive), you should have flavors sorted by cakeId and then binary search on cakeId. It will be `nlogn` complexity instead of `n**2`.

Comment: Would this work for very large arrays length around 300k plus?

Comment: If you care much about space complexity I would recommend doing it in place. I will update my answer